# How to get the specific key in realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently having a trouble on deleting a specific data from my firebase. So basically I have recyclerview wherein my datas are displayed and I have a button in each data display there and that's EDIT button. Whenever I try to click the EDIT button it should intent me to another activity with the same data displayed in the recyclerview and there's a another button displayed there and that's DELETE button. But whenever I try to click the delete button, it deletes all the data from the child. I only need to DELETE the selected ID/Data that is passing when intent occurs.
Edit.

EditResearch.java

```
package com.example.citeresearchrepository.AdminPackage;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.citeresearchrepository.Model.ResearchRepository;
import com.example.citeresearchrepository.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

public class EditResearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editfilehandler_et,editrepo_title,editrepo_description,editrepo_currentdate;
    Button editrepo_savebtn;
    ImageView backbtn_editresearch;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    String researchtitle,researchdate,researchname,researchdescription;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_research);
        editfilehandler_et = findViewById(R.id.editfilehandler_et);
        editrepo_title = findViewById(R.id.editrepo_title);
        editrepo_description = findViewById(R.id.editrepo_description);
        editrepo_currentdate = findViewById(R.id.editrepo_currentdate);

        editrepo_savebtn = findViewById(R.id.editrepo_savebtn);
        backbtn_editresearch = findViewById(R.id.backbtn_editresearch);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        researchtitle = intent.getStringExtra("researchtitle");
        researchdate = intent.getStringExtra("researchdate");
        researchname = intent.getStringExtra("researchname");
        researchdescription = intent.getStringExtra("researchdescription");

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ResearchRepository");
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        editfilehandler_et.setText(researchname);
        editrepo_title.setText(researchtitle);
        editrepo_currentdate.setText(researchdate);
        editrepo_description.setText(researchdescription);

        editrepo_savebtn.setEnabled(false);
        editfilehandler_et.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectPDF();
            }
        });
        /* Update Files */

        backbtn_editresearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdminResearchRepoActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }
    private void selectPDF(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "PDF FILE SELECTED"), 12);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==12 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null && data.getData()!=null){
            editrepo_savebtn.setEnabled(true);
            editfilehandler_et.setText(data.getDataString().substring(data.getDataString().lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
            editrepo_savebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    deletePreviousImage();
                    uploadResearch(data.getData());
                }
            });
        }
    }
    private void deleteSelectedRow(){
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("ResearchRepository");
        databaseReference.removeValue();
    }
    private void uploadResearch(Uri data) {
        final String filecapture = editfilehandler_et.getText().toString();
        final String researchtitle = editrepo_title.getText().toString();
        final String researchdescription = editrepo_description.getText().toString();
        final String researchtimeline = editrepo_currentdate.getText().toString();
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("File Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference reference = storageReference.child("ResearchRepository" +System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf");

        reference.putFile(data).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while(!uriTask.isComplete());
                Uri uri = uriTask.getResult();

                ResearchRepository researchRepository = new ResearchRepository(filecapture,researchtitle,researchdescription,researchtimeline,uri.toString());
                databaseReference.child(databaseReference.push().getKey()).setValue(researchRepository);
                Toast.makeText(EditResearchActivity.this, "File Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                editfilehandler_et.setText("");
                editrepo_title.setText("");
                editrepo_currentdate.setText("");
                editrepo_description.setText("");
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdminResearchRepoActivity.class));

            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
                double progress = (100*snapshot.getBytesTransferred())/snapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                progressDialog.setMessage("File Uploading..."+(int)progress+"%");
            }
        });
    }
    private void deletePreviousImage(){
        StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(researchtitle);
        reference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(EditResearchActivity.this, "Previous File Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(EditResearchActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

AdminResearchRepoActivity.java

```
package com.example.citeresearchrepository.AdminPackage;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.citeresearchrepository.AdminAdapter.AdminRepoAdapter;
import com.example.citeresearchrepository.Model.ResearchRepository;
import com.example.citeresearchrepository.R;
import com.example.citeresearchrepository.ViewHolder.AdminResearchRepositoryViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdminResearchRepoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView adminrepo_backbtn;
    RecyclerView reporecycler;
    FloatingActionButton addresearch_btn;

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    AdminRepoAdapter adminRepoAdapter;
    ArrayList<ResearchRepository> researchRepositoryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_research_repo);

//      Buttons
        adminrepo_backbtn = findViewById(R.id.backbtn_adminrepo);
        addresearch_btn = findViewById(R.id.addresearch_btn);

        addresearch_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddResearchActivity.class));
            }
        });
        adminrepo_backbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeAdminActivity.class));
            }
        });

//      Recycler
        reporecycler = findViewById(R.id.reporecycler);
        reporecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

//      Firebase Connection
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ResearchRepository");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                researchRepositoryArrayList = new ArrayList<ResearchRepository>();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    ResearchRepository researchRepository = dataSnapshot.getValue(ResearchRepository.class);
                    researchRepositoryArrayList.add(researchRepository);
                }
                adminRepoAdapter = new AdminRepoAdapter(AdminResearchRepoActivity.this,researchRepositoryArrayList);
                reporecycler.setAdapter(adminRepoAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(AdminResearchRepoActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

AdminRepoAdapter.java

```
package com.example.citeresearchrepository.AdminAdapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.citeresearchrepository.AdminPackage.EditResearchActivity;
import com.example.citeresearchrepository.Model.ResearchRepository;
import com.example.citeresearchrepository.R;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdminRepoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdminRepoAdapter.AdminViewHolder>  {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<ResearchRepository> researchRepositories;

    public AdminRepoAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<ResearchRepository> repositories){
        context = c;
        researchRepositories = repositories;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdminViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new AdminViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.admineditrepo_row,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdminViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.researchtitle_view.setText(researchRepositories.get(position).getResearchtitle());
        holder.researchdate_view.setText(researchRepositories.get(position).getResearchtimeline());
        holder.researchname_view.setText(researchRepositories.get(position).getFilecapture());
        holder.researchdescription_view.setText(researchRepositories.get(position).getResearchdescription());
        holder.btnpdf_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditResearchActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("researchtitle",researchRepositories.get(position).getResearchtitle());
                intent.putExtra("researchdate",researchRepositories.get(position).getResearchtimeline());
                intent.putExtra("researchname",researchRepositories.get(position).getFilecapture());
                intent.putExtra("researchdescription",researchRepositories.get(position).getResearchdescription());
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return researchRepositories.size();
    }

    class AdminViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView researchtitle_view,researchdate_view,researchname_view,researchdescription_view,researchtitle_url;
        public Button btnpdf_edit;

        public AdminViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            researchtitle_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.researchtitle_view);
            researchdate_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.researchdate_view);
            researchname_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.researchname_view);
            researchdescription_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.researchdescription_view);
            researchtitle_url = itemView.findViewById(R.id.researchtitle_view);
            btnpdf_edit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnpdf_edit);
        }
    }
}
```

ResearchRepository.class

```
package com.example.citeresearchrepository.Model;

public class ResearchRepository {

    public String filecapture;
    public String researchtitle;
    public String researchdescription;
    public String researchtimeline;
    public String url;

    public ResearchRepository() {
    }

    public ResearchRepository(String filecapture, String researchtitle, String researchdescription, String researchtimeline, String url) {
        this.filecapture = filecapture;
        this.researchtitle = researchtitle;
        this.researchdescription = researchdescription;
        this.researchtimeline = researchtimeline;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getFilecapture() {
        return filecapture;
    }

    public void setFilecapture(String filecapture) {
        this.filecapture = filecapture;
    }

    public String getResearchtitle() {
        return researchtitle;
    }

    public void setResearchtitle(String researchtitle) {
        this.researchtitle = researchtitle;
    }

    public String getResearchdescription() {
        return researchdescription;
    }

    public void setResearchdescription(String researchdescription) {
        this.researchdescription = researchdescription;
    }

    public String getResearchtimeline() {
        return researchtimeline;
    }

    public void setResearchtimeline(String researchtimeline) {
        this.researchtimeline = researchtimeline;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Here's my realtime-database : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lML0i.png
I just wanna delete the red box.

Comment: Please post your recyclerview code

Comment: @Ashish hello, I have updated my codes. Thank you

Comment: please post `ResearchRepository` class

Comment: @Ashish I have posted it, sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see you are getting an instance to only the ResearchRepository node instead of the specific child node that you want to delete. You need to keep track of the unique IDs you are pushing on to the ResearchRepository node and pass it in the intent as well;

Add the code to pass the unique ID of the ResearchRepository child you want to delete.
Then do this in your new activity where the delete code is present.

```
String childToDelete; //retrieve the value from the intent
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ResearchRepository").child(childToDelete);
databaseReference.removeValue();
```

This should do it if that is your purpose.

**Edit 1**:-
I got your point. Please follow the approach I will be showing now and it will work for you.

Edit your class as shown below:-

AdminRepoAdapter.java

```
public class AdminRepoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdminRepoAdapter.AdminViewHolder>  {

    Context context;
    Map<String,ResearchRepository> researchRepositories;
    ArrayList<ResearchRepository> researchRepositoriesHolder;

    public AdminRepoAdapter(Context c, Map<String,ResearchRepository> repositories){
        context = c;
        researchRepositories = repositories;
        researchRepositoriesHolder = new ArrayList<>(researchRepositories.values());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdminViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new AdminViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.admineditrepo_row,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdminViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.researchtitle_view.setText(researchRepositoriesHolder.get(position).getResearchtitle());
        holder.researchdate_view.setText(researchRepositoriesHolder.get(position).getResearchtimeline());
        holder.researchname_view.setText(researchRepositoriesHOlder.get(position).getFilecapture());
        holder.researchdescription_view.setText(researchRepositoriesHolder.get(position).getResearchdescription());
        holder.btnpdf_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Map.Entry<String,ResearchRepository> entry = null; //Just for initialization
                for (Map.Entry<String,ResearchRepository> var : researchRepositories.entrySet()) {
                    if(var.getValue() == researchRepositoriesHolder.get(position)){
                       entry = var;
                       break;
                    }
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditResearchActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("researchtitle",entry.getValue().getResearchtitle());
                intent.putExtra("researchdate",entry.getValue().getResearchtimeline());
                intent.putExtra("researchname",entry.getValue().getFilecapture());
                intent.putExtra("researchdescription",entry.getValue().getResearchdescription());
                intent.putExtra("childNodeKey",entry.getKey());
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return researchRepositoriesHolder.size();
    }

    class AdminViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView researchtitle_view,researchdate_view,researchname_view,researchdescription_view,researchtitle_url;
        public Button btnpdf_edit;

        public AdminViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            researchtitle_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.researchtitle_view);
            researchdate_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.researchdate_view);
            researchname_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.researchname_view);
            researchdescription_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.researchdescription_view);
            researchtitle_url = itemView.findViewById(R.id.researchtitle_view);
            btnpdf_edit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnpdf_edit);
        }
    }
}
```

AdminResearchRepoActivity.java

```
public class AdminResearchRepoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView adminrepo_backbtn;
    RecyclerView reporecycler;
    FloatingActionButton addresearch_btn;

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    AdminRepoAdapter adminRepoAdapter;
    Map<String, ResearchRepository> researchRepositoryMap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_research_repo);

//      Buttons
        adminrepo_backbtn = findViewById(R.id.backbtn_adminrepo);
        addresearch_btn = findViewById(R.id.addresearch_btn);

        addresearch_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddResearchActivity.class));
            }
        });
        adminrepo_backbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeAdminActivity.class));
            }
        });

//      Recycler
        reporecycler = findViewById(R.id.reporecycler);
        reporecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

//      Firebase Connection
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ResearchRepository");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                researchRepositoryMap = (Map)snapshot.getValue()
                adminRepoAdapter = new AdminRepoAdapter(AdminResearchRepoActivity.this,researchRepositoryMap);
                reporecycler.setAdapter(adminRepoAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(AdminResearchRepoActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

In this way when you pass a Intent from your AdminRepoAdapter to EditResearchActivity you will have the key stored as 'childNodeKey' in your intent.
You can then follow the procedure I mentioned before the edit to delete using the key you got from here.

Comment: Hello, Raja. I would like to ask, so basically I have to retrieve the Child Key from the Recyclerview onbindviewholder, and getintent it to the activity where delete button is present? I'm sorry I'm confused. on how do I store the child key to String childToDelete that you were referring.

Comment: Raja, he is asking how to get that node details

Comment: @Ashish yea I wanna get that unique key and delete that but yeah it deletes everything.

Comment: @Kai see my answer might help you

Comment: My point is instead of retrieving the ResearchRepository objects from your database as an ArrayList retrieve them as a Map from your snapshot. The Map will contain the key as the unique ID you wanted and the value will be the corresponing ResearchRepository. You can then pass the Map to your RecyclerView instead of an array and populate it accordingly. You can then retrieve the ID of the item you wanted from the Map and populate it in your intent. You have to change the way you retrieve the values and populate your ArrayList in your AdminRepoAdapter. In this way you can get your keys.

Comment: @Kai I added an edit to my answer Kai. Check that out. Hope it helps.

Comment: @RajaShekar Hello, I'm having trouble with .stream there's an error and suggesting me to add @RequiresApn(N) and surround with sdk 
`.stream()
                        .filter(x -> x.getValue().equals(researchRepositoriesHolder.get(position)))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
` im having error here.

Comment: @Kai Your minimum API level is less than 24 so it won't allow streams. I will update the answer so you can just use a for loop instead of stream

Comment: @Kai I have edited the answer. It will work now without any errors. Better use this structure where you keep track of keys and values because these keys are randomly generated and you won't know the value whenever you want. Always prefer a Map over an ArrayList while using Firebase